# How Can I re-attach my bathroom fixtures which are hanging loose from the wall?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, silicone

Please see the two pictures below. I'm trying to re-attach the two faucets so that there is no gap between them and the wall. These faucets work perfectly fine its just that they aren't attached to the wall as they should be.

Is this something I'd need a plumber for? or What would I need to buy/do to get this in order?

[image: Gap between faucet and the wall]

[image: Gap between faucet and the wall]

Comment: Are you able to press them up against the wall but they don't stay put?

Comment: That is correct. I can push them up against the wall but they don't stay up.

Answer (score 4):

Escutcheon =  the cover plate used over a hole in a surface that exists to allow a pipe/fitting to go through the wall.

Your first picture looks like it's a simple case of the escutcheon needing to be re-caulked.  Using a scraper, clean the existing caulk completely from the wall, then apply a new clean bead of bathroom grade white silicon caulk around the escutcheon and hold it in place until the caulk sets.  In this case the caulk is both sealant and adhesive.

Your second picture - how loose is the tub spout?  Caulk won't hold it in place - too much water pressure on the spout - there should be some kind of set screw or other means of getting the spout up tight to the wall.  Once you lock the spout in place, seal it with caulk like with the escutcheon.